# didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation firing Twice when Rotated

Tags: ios, objective-c

I realize that `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` is deprecated in iOS 8; however, I have an app that needs to remain compatible with iOS7.  The problem I am having is that when the device is rotated (iPad in this case) this method is being called twice.  This happens on an actual device as well as with the simulator.  I have simply put an NSLog in the method to show this.

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation 
{

        NSLog(@"didRotateCalled");
}
```

I have also checked the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` but that one works correctly only getting called once.

Any thoughts why the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation` method would be fired twice per rotation?

As a quick update.  I put a breakpoint in which revealed something interesting.  This view is a `UISplitviewcontroller` and it looks like the method is called first for the `UISplitviewcontroller` and then as a `UIViewController`.  Not sure why...

Some additional information.  I am using Storyboards one for iPhone and the other iPad.  The iPhone does not use the `splitViewController`.  The code base is shared so in the `prepareForSegue` I do the following:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
            UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.view.window.rootViewController;
            splitViewController.delegate = segue.destinationViewController;
}
```

Comment: Print out the `fromInterfaceOrientation`. What do you get?

Comment: list the ViewController classes you are using and where you have implemented the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`. It might be your method is called from different instances or from code in class and superclass.

Comment: Master split is a UITableViewController and the detail portion is a UIViewController.  When a cell is selected on the master side the detail is "replaced" with the appropriate content.  You can see in my code above the setup for that in preareForSegue.

Comment: Also, the didRotate method in question is within the detail view.

Comment: As a test I quickly put the didRotate method in the master split and it also fires twice on rotation.

Comment: So I tried the iOS 8 method: -(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator which seems to work and is only called once.  My app is targeting iOS 7.1 and above.  Will this method work on those devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have my answer. I just downloaded the simulators for iOS 7.1 for use within the latest Xcode. I found that the `viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator` method is NOT called when running under iOS 7.1. However, I also found that the issue I described with the rotation firing twice does NOT happen with the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method in iOS7 but again it DOES in iOS 8. This is a clear bug at Apple.

It looks like I will need to detect the OS version the customer is running and if it is iOS 8 or above I will not have it execute any code in the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method. I can, however, leave the `viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator` method in there for iOS 8 devices as this method will just be ignored by iOS 7.

I don't know if this is just a problem for splitviewcontrollers or for all view methods using rotation between iOS 7 and 8. If your app is not overriding this method than you'd never know. If it is you will face what I did above. Not good.

Here is the code I am using to check for version:

```
-(void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    if (NSFoundationVersionNumber == NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_1) // use this only for iOS7 devices as otherwise this fires twice under iOS8
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I have left `-(void)viewWillTransitionToSize:(CGSize)size withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator` method as this will simply be ignored by iOS 7 devices but will be called by iOS 8.x and presumably above.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue (though in my case willRotate is executed twice on iOS 8 as well). I used the following workaround:

```
BOOL _willRotate; // iVar for the state

// Methods that should be called from willRotate/didRotate (can be inline)
- (BOOL)workaroundIOS8RotationMethodsCalledTwice_forWillRotate_shouldExecute
{
    if(_willRotate) {
        return NO;
    }
    _willRotate = YES;
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)workaroundIOS8RotationMethodsCalledTwice_forDidRotate_shouldExecute
{
    if(_willRotate) {
        _willRotate = NO;
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

// Inside willRotate (return if shouldn't execute):
if(![self workaroundIOS8RotationMethodsCalledTwice_forWillRotate_shouldExecute]) {
    return;
}

// Inside didRotate (return if shouldn't execute):
if(![self workaroundIOS8RotationMethodsCalledTwice_forDidRotate_shouldExecute]) {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found `viewWillTransition` called twice against different `UIViewController` instances. On first call, self is valid instance. But on second call, self is invalid. `viewDidLoad()` is not called on this invalid instance.
I add a member and set value on `viewDidLoad`, then check self is valid or not.

```
class MyViewControler: UIViewController {
  var last_width:CGFloat?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(" viewDidLoad self \(self) has address: \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())")
    last_width = self.view.bounds.width
  }

  override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    print(" viewWillTransition self \(self) has address: \(Unmanaged.passUnretained(self).toOpaque())")
    // Bug? viewWillTransition called twice with diffent self instance, ignore second call
    if (last_width == nil || last_width == size.width) {
        return
    }
    last_width = size.width
  }
}
```